# How to create Automation Task "Delete old blobs" with ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

After creating a "Delete old blobs" automation task from my Azure Storage account in Azure Portal, I obtained 2 resources: a LogicApp and an API connection automatically called "azureblob-MyStorageName".

I exported the ARM template of the LogicApp to create the LogicApp again from scratch. But the deployment failed.

With this end of the ARM template:

```
"parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/francecentral/managedApis/azureblob",
                "connectionName": "azureblob-mystorageaccountname",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'azureblob-mystorageaccountname')]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
Error:The managedBy resource id is missing in workflow 'CleanBlob-Daily'. ManagedBy must be provided if resource kind is 'AutomationTask'. Click here for details
```

In this Microsoft article [Microsoft.Web locations/managedApis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/locations/managedapis?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), it says to use a reference to create Api Connection which can't deployed because in read-only.

But with this end of the ARM template using reference:

```
"parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "id": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', '{azureblob}'), '2016-06-01')]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('apiConnectionName')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'azureblob-kpmgfrsasbxdocs0002')]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'CleanBlob-Daily' at line '1' and column '1335' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis' requires '2' resource name argument(s). Please see https://aka.ms/arm-resource-functions/#resourceid for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)
```

Then, how to create a "Delete old blobs" automation task with ARM ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new logic app using the code generated from **Delete old blobs** automation task and have done few modification in it. I am deploying it using ARM template.

**Code**-

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "{LogicApp_Name}",
      "location": "eastus",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Delete_blob": {
                                "description": "If blob is older than the expiration age, delete it",
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "delete",
                                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Id']))}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "description": "Check LastModified timestamp and whether older than the expiration age variable",
                        "expression": "@less(ticks(items('For_each')?['LastModified']), ticks(addDays(utcnow(), if(equals(parameters('Time'),'Days'), variables('ExpirationAgeInDays'), if(equals(parameters('Time'), 'Weeks'), mul(variables('ExpirationAgeInDays'), 7), if(equals(parameters('Time'),'Months'), mul(variables('ExpirationAgeInDays'), 30), variables('ExpirationAgeInDays')))))))",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "description": "Scan all blobs in this folder",
                "foreach": "@body('List_blobs')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "List_blobs": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "List_blobs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('BlobFolder')))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "useFlatListing": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Set_expiration_age_variable_": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "paginationPolicy": {
                        "minimumItemCount": 5000
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Set_expiration_age_variable_": {
                "description": "A variable to configure the auto expiration age in days. Default is 30 (30 days old).",
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "ExpirationAgeInDays",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": "@if(greater(parameters('ExpirationAge'), 0), mul(parameters('ExpirationAge'), -1), parameters('ExpirationAge'))"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            },
            "BlobFolder": {
                "defaultValue": "demo",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Blob container name",
                    "isLinkedResource": false,
                    "placeholder": "",
                    "required": true
                },
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ExpirationAge": {
                "defaultValue": 10,
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "Blobs older than this age will be deleted",
                    "displayName": "Expiration age",
                    "isLinkedResource": false,
                    "required": true
                },
                "type": "Int"
            },
            "Time": {
                "allowedValues": [
                    "Days",
                    "Weeks",
                    "Months"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "Days",
                "metadata": {
                    "allowedValues": [
                        "Days",
                        "Weeks",
                        "Months"
                    ],
                    "displayName": "Time Unit",
                    "isLinkedResource": false,
                    "placeholder": "Days",
                    "required": true
                },
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "azureblob": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/{Subscription_Id}/resourceGroups/{Resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-afrinstore01",
                "connectionName": "azureblob-afrinstore01",
                "id": "/subscriptions/{Subscription_Id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please add your connection parameters. I have deployed using `az deployment group create --resource-group <resourceGroup_Name> --template-file <ARM_File_Name.json>` command.

I have got successful result.

[image]